# displaying message with setTimeOut and clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I am working on a credit card checker project. The validation code works (so I don't include the code for it) but I want to go a step further:
the user types in a number and gets a reply. If the card is not valid they get "This card is not valid" in red, if it is, the answer is in green. The message disappears after a given time (setTimeout). The problem is it only works once. One time for valid and one for invalid.

I know it has something to do with timeoutId and clearTimeout but I've been chasing my own tail around trying to get it right. Probably because I don't fully understand it yet.

HTML:

```
<div class="credit-card">
      <p class="credit-card__text">Want to check you if your credit card is valid?</p>

      <input type="number" id="userInput" class="js-input" placeholder="type in your number and press ENTER" onkeydown="handleEnter(event)">

<div>
        <p id="js-return-valid"></p>
        <p id="js-return-invalid"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    const displayValid = document.getElementById('js-return-valid');
    const displayInvalid = document.getElementById('js-return-invalid');
    let input  = '';

    
    function handleEnter(event) {
      
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        input = String(input).split('').map((input
        ) => { return Number(input) });
        
        validateCred(input);  

        if (!validateCred(input)) { 
         
            setTimeout(function() {
                displayInvalid.style.display = "none";
            }, 2000);
            
            displayInvalid.innerHTML = `This number is not valid.`;
         
        } else {
           
            setTimeout(function() {
                displayValid.style.display = "none";
            }, 2000);

            displayValid.innerHTML = `This number is valid.`;
         }

      document.getElementById("userInput").value = null;

        } 
    }
```

Comment: As far as I follow the logic, you set `display: none` style and then don't reset it again after timeout is cleared.

Comment: just instead of set display none you can reset innerHTML value to empty on both place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always clear any existing timeout before starting a new one. This ensures that the message will always show for the full duration even if the user rapidly presses the Enter key multiple times.
- Reset the display properties of both displayValid and displayInvalid so that they're both potentially available to show messages again.

  ```
  const displayValid = document.getElementById('js-return-valid');
  const displayInvalid = document.getElementById('js-return-invalid');
  let input  = '';
  let timeoutId;

   function handleEnter(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
   const input = document.getElementById("userInput").value.split('').map(Number);

   // Check for empty input
   if (input.length === 0) {
       displayValid.style.display = 'none';
       displayInvalid.style.display = 'none';
       return;
   }

   // Reset style and clear timeouts
   displayValid.style.display = "block";
   displayInvalid.style.display = "block";
   clearTimeout(validTimeoutId);
   clearTimeout(invalidTimeoutId);

   if (validateCred(input)) {
       displayValid.textContent = 'This number is valid.';
       displayInvalid.style.display = 'none';
       validTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
           displayValid.style.display = 'none';
       }, 2000);
   } else {
       displayInvalid.textContent = 'This number is not valid.';
       displayValid.style.display = 'none';
       invalidTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
           displayInvalid.style.display = 'none';
       }, 2000);
   }

   document.getElementById("userInput").value = null;
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: IMO, both displayValid & displayValid should be hidden by default and only be shown if there is a message as they will take space in UI.

Comment: Display: none removes the element from DOM but visibility:hidden takes place in the DOM.

Comment: Indeed, setting display to "block" will make them take space in case of valid card and either of them will take space in case of error.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. It now makes sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran into another issue. First, if I press Enter when the input field is empty, it displays "valid". Second, if I use valid number/invalid number interchangeably it is fine, but when I use a number of the same validation, settimout counts from the first one, so the message for the second numer is visible only for a fraction of a time.

Comment: You might need to update your function little bit. wait. please check my answer again. I edited.